# GCC can't compile a runnable Hello World in Cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

With this makefile:

```
TARGET    = main.exe
OBJECT_01 = main.o
SOURCE_01 = main.c

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_01)
    gcc -g -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECT_01) -lstdc++

$(OBJECT_01) : $(SOURCE_01)
    gcc -g -c $(SOURCE_01) -o $(OBJECT_01)

all : $(TARGET)

clean :
    -rm $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

And it compiles into main.exe just fine, but when i try to run it with ./main.exe it says that the file doesn't exist and deletes it.

Am i missing some cygwin package or something?

Upd: Here's the full terminal command sequence:

```
andrey@andrey-PC ~/gcc-test
$ ls
main.c  main.exe  main.o  makefile

andrey@andrey-PC ~/gcc-test
$ make clean
rm main.exe

andrey@andrey-PC ~/gcc-test
$ make
gcc -g -o main.exe main.o

andrey@andrey-PC ~/gcc-test
$ ls
main.c  main.exe  main.o  makefile

andrey@andrey-PC ~/gcc-test
$ ./main.exe
-bash: ./main.exe: No such file or directory

andrey@andrey-PC ~/gcc-test
$ ls
main.c  main.o  makefile
```

Comment: If it's a C program, why whould you link it with a c++ library?

Comment: Your makefile looks fine, not sure why you link with `-lstdc++`. gcc will link C library automatically for a C program. You might as well remove `-lstdc++`. After compiling, it does produce `main.exec` right?

Comment: @BlueMoon Exactly the same thing occurs when -lstdc++ is removed.

Comment: @andreyg I wasn't suggesting removing `-libstd++` would solve it. That's a relevant note since you have C code. Before executing `main.exec`, do you actually see the `main.exe` getting generated?

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Didn't know that lstdc++ thing is a c++ library, picked the makefile form a tutorial.

Comment: @BlueMoon Yes, main.exe is being generated. I've added the full command sequence in the original post.

Comment: Could it be that some virus checker goes haywire? What's the result if you replace `main.exe` with just `main` in the `Makefile`? Cygwin will still generate it with the name `main.exe`, and I don't know why it should make a difference, but maybe it's still worth a try. Just wildly guessing...

Comment: Anti-virus software gone bad is my first guess too, but in that case, I wouldn't expect `main` vs. `main.exe` to make a difference. It should be easy enough to check whether that's to blame: anti-virus software typically has an option to list which threats it has found and removed.

Comment: You know what? It was my anti-virus being a bully. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but hopefully interesting and helpful for you: Your `Makefile` is far too complicated.
The following `Makefile` will perfectly well do the job for you:

```
CFLAGS+=-g

.PHONY: all
all: main

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) main.o main
```

(Most `Makefile` tutorials are bad, and I haven't seen a good one yet - sorry that I have to say a rant like that, but I really believe it's important and true.)

Comment: Not only not a direct answer, but not an answer to the question as asked at all.